# average of specific values of list of dictionary values python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hey I'm trying to get the average of values from a list the list has values from a dictionary I keep returning this error

```
all_students_avg = sum(numbers_lists) / len(numbers_lists)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I don't understand, the values I'm calling are are integers already and I've tried converting them to integers and float.

```
Bob = {'name': 'bob', 'assignments': 80.0, 'presentation': 80.0, 'lab tasks': 60.0}
Geoff = {'name': 'Geoff', 'assignments': 90.0, 'presentation': 90.0, 'lab tasks': 90.0}
numbers_lists = [Bob['assignments'], Bob['presentation'], Bob['lab tasks']], [Geoff['assignments'], "\n",
                                                                          Geoff['presentation'],
                                                                          Geoff['lab tasks']]
all_students_avg = sum(numbers_lists) / len(numbers_lists)
print("This is all the students average score across all subjects: ", all_students_avg, )
```

Comment: A list has this format, `numbers_lists = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, ...]` Did you have that?

Comment: `numbers_lists` is a tuple of lists, which is why you're getting the error. You need to flatten your tuple into a list of numbers in order for `sum()` to work.

Comment: numbers = int(numbers_list)  and.. avg = sum(numbers) / sum(numbers) (im not sure)

Comment: That is not correct @httpanand

Comment: ooh ok  @ddejohn

Answer (score 1):

Python list has a format like: `l = [element1, element2, element3]`. Your list was looking like: `numbers_lists = [[element1, element2], "\n", [elem1, elem2]]` because your list not only include two lists but it also contains a newline character that can't be summed with integer.

I made a little modification to your code and this should work:

```
Bob = {'name': 'bob', 'assignments': 80.0, 'presentation': 80.0, 'lab tasks': 60.0}
Geoff = {'name': 'Geoff', 'assignments': 90.0, 'presentation': 90.0, 'lab tasks': 90.0}
bob_scores = [Bob['assignments'], Bob['presentation'], Bob['lab tasks']]
geoff_scores = [Geoff['assignments'], Geoff['presentation'], Geoff['lab tasks']]
                                                                                                                                           
numbers_lists = bob_scores + geoff_scores
all_students_avg = sum(numbers_lists) / len(numbers_lists)
print("This is all the students average score across all subjects: ", all_students_avg)
```

output:

```
This is all the students average score across all subjects:  81.66666666666667
```

Comment: I recommend using `bob_scores` and `geoff_scores` as your variables or something else more distinguishable from `Bob` and `Geoff`. I suggest also explaining what's wrong with OP's code.

Comment: @ddejohn I've updated the variables as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: okay so my mistakes were having a newline in the list and having 2 lists within the numbers_lists

Comment: Yep, the python ```sum``` function takes a list, tuple, dict, set and range of numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because the variable `numbers_lists` is in list format.
You may try this

```
print(numbers_lists)
```

Inorder to handle this problem, you can convert all elements to integers using `map()`.

```
num_list = list(map(int,numbers_lists))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your list structure is not going to work as you expect it to. The list you have will need to be unpacked as seen here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp.

You could add extra brackets to the ends to make a list of multiple lists.

```
Bob = {'name': 'bob', 'assignments': 80.0, 'presentation': 80.0, 'lab tasks': 60.0}
Geoff = {'name': 'Geoff', 'assignments': 90.0, 'presentation': 90.0, 'lab tasks': 90.0}
# if you want 2 seperate lists you could "unpack" them like this
numbers_lists1, number_lists2 = [Bob['assignments'], Bob['presentation'], Bob['lab tasks']], [Geoff['assignments'], "\n",
                                                                          Geoff['presentation'],
                                                                          Geoff['lab tasks']]
print(numbers_lists1)
print(number_lists2)

# if you want a list with 2 lists in it you will need to add extra [] on the ends
fixed_numbers_lists = [[Bob['assignments'], Bob['presentation'], Bob['lab tasks']], [Geoff['assignments'], "\n",
                                                                          Geoff['presentation'],
                                                                          Geoff['lab tasks']]]
print(fixed_numbers_lists)
```